# How to add a v-on:change attribute on a select tag using tag helper in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, vuejs2

I'm trying to ad the v-on:change attribute on a select element generated with select_tag

Something like this

```
 <%= select_tag "worker_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@workers, "id", "name"), prompt: 'Choose', class: 'form-control', data: { "v-on:change" => "getWorker()" } %>
```

Also tried

```
<%= select_tag "worker_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@workers, "id", "name"), prompt: 'Choose', {}, { class: 'form-control', "v-on:change" => "getWorker()" } %>
```

Still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<%= select_tag "worker_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@workers, "id", "name"), prompt: 'Choose', class: 'form-control', '@change': 'getWorker' %>
```

Or:

```
<%= select_tag "worker_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@workers, "id", "name"), prompt: 'Choose', class: 'form-control', 'v-on:change': 'getWorker' %>
```

Comment: Yeah, I was under the impression it didn't make a difference if `()` was there or not. But, still, I edited the answer to make it more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

The correct version was to use @change and =>

```
<%= select_tag "worker_id", options_from_collection_for_select(@workers, "id", "name"), prompt: 'Choose', class: 'form-control', '@change' => 'getWorker' %>
```